# Merge array of arrays based sub array index as keys (NodeJS/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

How to write a code that would merge my list in the following way? Performance is important. I want to convert the following array:

```
"list": [
    [
        "marketing",
        "page_sections",
        "PageOne"
    ],
    [
        "marketing",
        "page_sections",
        "PageTwo"
    ],
    [
        "webapp",
        "page",
        "pageone"
    ],
    [
        "webapp",
        "page",
        "pagetwo"
    ],
```

To the following format:

```
[   
    {
     name: "marketing",
     path: "marketing/",           
     children: [
                    {
                        name: "page_sections",
                        path: "marketing/page_sections", 
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "pageOne",
                                path: "marketing/page_sections/pageOne", 
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                name: "pageTwo",
                                path: "marketing/page_sections/pageTwo", 
                                children: []
                            },
                       }
           ],
     },
    {
     name: "webapp",
     path: "webapp/"
     children: [
                  {
                    name: "page",
                    path: "webapp/page/"
                    
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "pageone",
                            path: "webapp/page/pageone"
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "pagetwo",
                            path: "webapp/page/pagetwo"
                            children: []
                        },
                    }
             ]
     },
]
```

The first index of sub array is parent, second index is child of parent, third index is child of second index (and so on).

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Javascript,

Comment: @Keith The expected output is json. For now I'll convert it into JS object to make it easier. I just need help in converting the above array to the output. Any reference will really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, and your expected result.

What I would do is loop the `list`, and then do another loop inside the list.  Mix this with `Array.find`..

Eg..

```js
const data = {list:[
  ["marketing","page_sections","PageOne"],
  ["marketing","page_sections","PageTwo"],
  ["webapp","page","pageone"],
  ["webapp","page","pagetwo"]]};
  

function makeTree(src) {
  const root = [];
  for (const s of src) {
    let r = root;
    let path = '';
    for (const name of s) {
      path += `${name}/`;
      let f = r.find(k => k.name === name);
      if (!f) r.push(f = {name, path, children: []});
      r = f.children;
    }
  }
  return root;
}
   
console.log(makeTree(data.list));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The shortest approach is to iterate the nested names and look for an object with the same name. If not exist, create a new object. Return the `children` array as new level.

This approach features [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for iterating the outer array of `data` and for all inner arrays.

```js
const
    data = [["marketing", "page_sections", "PageOne"], ["marketing", "page_sections", "PageTwo"], ["webapp", "page", "pageone"], ["webapp", "page", "pagetwo"]],
    result = data.reduce((r, names) => {
        names.reduce((level, name, i, values) => {
            let temp = level.find(q => q.name === name),
                path = values.slice(0, i + 1).join('/') + (i ? '' : '/');
            if (!temp) level.push(temp = { name, path, children: [] });
            return temp.children;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```js
list= [
    [
        "marketing",
        "page_sections",
        "PageOne"
    ],
    [
        "marketing",
        "page_sections",
        "PageTwo"
    ],
    [
        "webapp",
        "page",
        "pageone"
    ],
    [
        "webapp",
        "page",
        "pagetwo"
    ],
  ];


getChildrenItem = (arr) => {
  if(arr.length === 1) {
    return { name: arr[0], children: []};
  } else {
    return { name: arr.splice(0,1)[0], children: [getChildrenItem([...arr])]};
  }
  
}

merge = (srcArr, newObj) => {
  const {name, children} = newObj;
  let index = srcArr.findIndex(item => item.name === name);
  if( index> -1) {
    children.forEach(item => merge(srcArr[index].children, item))
    return ;
  } else {
    srcArr.push(newObj);
    return;
  }
}

allObj = [];
list.forEach(item => {
  let tempObj = getChildrenItem([...item]);
  merge(allObj, tempObj);
});

console.log(allObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Performance is an issue, I think this is one of the best solutions.

```
let list = [
  ["marketing", "page_sections", "PageOne"],
  ["marketing", "page_sections", "PageTwo"],
  ["webapp", "page", "pageone"],
  ["webapp", "page", "pagetwo"],
];
const dt = {};
const pushToOBJ = (Object, name) => {
  if (Object[name]) return Object[name];
  Object[name] = {
    name,
    children: {},
  };
  return Object[name];
};

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  let subArray = list[i];
  let st = pushToOBJ(dt, subArray[0]);
  for (let j = 1; j < subArray.length; j++) {
    st = pushToOBJ(st.children, subArray[j]);
  }
}
let result = [];
const convertObjToChildArray = (obj) => {
  if (obj === {}) return [];

  let arr = Object.values(obj);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].children = convertObjToChildArray(arr[i].children);
  }
  return arr;
};
result = convertObjToChildArray(dt);
console.log(result);
```

No Use of JS find function, which already has O(n) Complexity.